# How to invoke a Servlet (doGet) in a web application on startup?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, startup

I need to invoke a Servlet on application startup since it contains some application initialization logic.

I know I can set load-on-startup configuration, but this will only invoke Servlet’s init method. I need to invoke a doGet method and pass some Url parameters to it. 
Servlet doGet method expects ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects.

Also, since this is clustered application, I need to know exactly what node I am accessing (since one option is just to open a socket and invoke a Servlet).

What is the best option to perform this?

EDIT: As a clarification, Servlet already exist and can not be modified. Until now, someone would manually invoke the Servlet from the browser. I need to automatize this.

Comment: Since this appears not to be your own code ("I can't fix it"), I strongly recommend to report this huge flaw to the developer/maintainer of the servlet in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to refactor whatever logic you have in the `doGet` method into a separate method that can be invoked both from `init` and `doGet`.

If you really can't refactor the logic (which really is the only good option), you can use some mock library. Google says [Spring's mock objects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html)  are popular.

Having a usable implementation of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`, make a servlet loaded with `load-on-startup`, and from its `init` method, locate the relevant servlet from the current `ServletContext`, and invoke `doGet` with the appropriate request and response objects. (Yes, it's a pretty bad kludge, but you'll have to do something like this.)

**Edit:** If you don't want to hack the WAR file, maybe you should check if your servlet container has the possibility to run some kind of hooks after you re/deploy a web app.

Comment: +1:  Never mix application logic with startup logic.  A) first call of your app could take forever (which is somewhat irrelevant if you're using Google App Engine).  B) It's a horrible kludge.  Put your init stuff in Servlet::init()

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the option in my case.

Comment: I am not sure how mock objects come into play here?

Comment: thanks gustafc, I will try the option with mocks. It should work as long the code isn't doing anything weird with these objects.

Comment: Why not just use ServletContextListener instead of all this hacks with mocks and deployment hooks?!

Comment: @Vasil, I agree that a context listener is cleaner than a servlet with `load-on-startup`, but the OP's problem is that they *have* to perform a `GET` request to a specific servlet.

Comment: @gustafc. ServletContextListener may be used in conjunction with dummy HttpServletRequest/Response (I assume, only request parameter maps need to be implemented) that same way as load-on-startup -- get initialized servlet from the context and explicitly call doGet.

Comment: @Vasil, yes - as I said, I agree. That doesn't reduce the kludginess of the solution by much, though, as the OP has to hack an existing WAR file.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, bootstrup initialization / shutdown cleanup is achieved with [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) - did you consider this option?
Alternatively, as an ugly hack, you can implement a servlet superclass with the initializtion logics, that will be called just once.

Comment: what do you mean by "you can implement a servlet superclass with the initializtion logics, that will be called just once."?

Comment: This approach is used in lots of web frameworks (e.g., Jersey). All the servlets are inherited from the super-servlet, that contains generic logics and bootstrupping functionality (which is invoked just once in a lazy-loading manner, when any child-servlet is called).

Answer (score 0):

This is in one word *terrible*, but you could use [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)/[`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) for this.

```
new URL("http://localhost/yourservlet").openStream();
```

Comment: how do I get the servlet URL without configuring it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this by using java.lang.Runtime. Its worked for me perfectly. You can override init method in which servlet(here my servlet name is BackEndServlet) you have to call either doGet or doPost method.

```
@Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080"+config.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/BackEndServlet"; 
        System.out.println(url);
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        try{

            if (os.indexOf( "win" ) >= 0) {

                // this doesn't support showing urls in the form of "page.html#nameLink" 
                rt.exec( "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);

            } else if (os.indexOf( "mac" ) >= 0) {

                rt.exec( "open " + url);

            } else if (os.indexOf( "nix") >=0 || os.indexOf( "nux") >=0) {

                // Do a best guess on unix until we get a platform independent way
                // Build a list of browsers to try, in this order.
                String[] browsers = {"epiphany", "firefox", "mozilla", "konqueror",
                                     "netscape","opera","links","lynx"};

                // Build a command string which looks like "browser1 "url" || browser2 "url" ||..."
                StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i=0; i<browsers.length; i++)
                    cmd.append( (i==0  ? "" : " || " ) + browsers[i] +" \"" + url + "\" ");

                rt.exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", cmd.toString() });

            } else {
                    return;
            }
           }catch (Exception e){
            return;
           }
          return;
    }
```